# Using M2Crypto to save and load X509 certs in pem files

Tags: python, cryptography, x509certificate, m2crypto, pem

I would expect that if I have a X509 cert as an object in memory, saved it as a pem file, then loaded it back in, I would end up with the same cert I started with. This seems not to be the case however. Let's call the original cert A, and the cert loaded from the pem file B. A.as_text() is identical to B.as_text(), but A.as_pem() differs from B.as_pem(). To say the least, I'm confused by this. As a side note, if A has been signed by another entity C, then A will verify against C's cert, but B will not.

I've put together a tiny sample program to demonstrate what I'm seeing. When I run this, the second RuntimeError is raised.

Thanks,
Brock

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

import M2Crypto as m2
import time

cur_time = m2.ASN1.ASN1_UTCTIME()
cur_time.set_time(int(time.time()) - 60*60*24)

expire_time = m2.ASN1.ASN1_UTCTIME()
# Expire certs in 1 hour.
expire_time.set_time(int(time.time()) + 60 * 60 * 24)


cs_rsa = m2.RSA.gen_key(1024, 65537, lambda: None)
cs_pk = m2.EVP.PKey()
cs_pk.assign_rsa(cs_rsa)
cs_cert = m2.X509.X509()

# These two seem the minimum necessary to make the as_text function call work
# at all
cs_cert.set_not_before(cur_time)
cs_cert.set_not_after(expire_time)

# This seems necessary to fill out the complete cert without errors.
cs_cert.set_pubkey(cs_pk)

# I've tried with the following set lines commented out and not commented.
cs_name = m2.X509.X509_Name()
cs_name.C = "US"
cs_name.ST = "CA"
cs_name.OU = "Fake Org CA 1"
cs_name.CN = "www.fakeorg.dex"
cs_name.Email = "cs1@www.fakeorg.dex"
cs_cert.set_subject(cs_name)
cs_cert.set_issuer_name(cs_name)
cs_cert.sign(cs_pk, md="sha256")

orig_text = cs_cert.as_text()
orig_pem = cs_cert.as_pem()

print "orig_text:\n%s" % orig_text

cs_cert.save_pem("/tmp/foo")

tcs = m2.X509.load_cert("/tmp/foo")

tcs_text = tcs.as_text()
tcs_pem = tcs.as_pem()

if orig_text != tcs_text:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Texts were different.\nOrig:\n%s\nAfter load:\n%s" %
            (orig_text, tcs_text))

if orig_pem != tcs_pem:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Pems were different.\nOrig:\n%s\nAfter load:\n%s" %
            (orig_pem, tcs_pem))
```

Comment: Do you tried to save tcs in the file? Is the file which you receive exactly as cs_cert have? It you have the same files, then in the first save_pem was made some kind of data conversion. If two files are different, you will be able dump the contain of the files (with OpenSSL utility or with CertUtil.exe -dump) and see what are different in both versions of the same certificate.

Comment: I didn't bother trying to save tcs in a file. Since tcs already didn't verify against the cert I signed cs with (not in this example but in the original code which lead me to eventually figure out this problem existed), saving tcs back to a file again didn't really help me. In any case, from everything I've read about pem files and x509 certs, certs which have different pem representations should have different text representations. Also, please note in the example that the TEXT of the certs is identical (according m2 and openssl), but the pem files are not. Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this with a cert that you created with OpenSSL command line tools (for example, the [server.pem](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/server.pem) in tests directory sans the key and text) by loading and saving it with M2Crypto, you should get identical files.

I thought [SimpleX509Create.py](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/contrib/SimpleX509create.py) in the contrib directory worked differently, but I tested it and I experience the same issue you found. Apparently there is some step we are missing that OpenSSL command line tools do.

Comment: It does work with OpenSSL created certs. Is there a bug I should follow for this issue or a place I should file a bug? Thanks.

Comment: It does work with OpenSSL created certs. Is there a bug I should follow for this issue or a place I should file a bug? Please note that the cert loaded from the file did not verify with the same CA cert that the m2 created cert did, so this is more than just a superficial issue. Thanks.

Comment: You could file a bug on M2Crypto: http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto#Bugzilla%20database